# bootstrap modal form not submitted

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following html code related to a bootstrap modal form.
When the user focus on a specific text field and press enter, the form is not submitted.
If, instead, I remove one of the two "input" tags (first or last name), it works (and the alert is shown). How could be?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-user" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Enter your name</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="contact_form" action="javascript:alert('test')"
                        method="POST">
                        First name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br />
                        Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="submitForm" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your `action` in your form tag should probably be an `onsubmit`.

Comment: thank you @JustinE . In reality is a little bit more than this. I've discovered that a form with more than 2 fields needs always to have a submit button in order to be correctly submitted (through the button or through the "return" key) even if you don't want that the user uses the button (in this case you can set display none to the button)

Comment: That is just not true. No form needs a submit button to submit. On form submission, a form's inputs are serialized, and posted or getted to the "action" path. Your action path set like that means that the serialized form will be submitted to a javascript function call which is seriously bad form.

Comment: In addition, input tags need to be closed. `<input name="" value="" />` instead of `<input name="" value="">`

Answer (score 2):

Put the send button inside form and make it `type='submit'`.

Comment: Or do this: `$("#submitForm").click(function() { $("#modal-user")[0].submit(); });`

Comment: To be clear, the answer is completely right and is the recommended way to do it for graceful support of non-js clients.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that a form with more than 2 fields needs always to have a submit button in order to be correctly submitted (through the button or through the "return" key) even if you don't want that the user uses the button (in this case you can set display none to the button)